# Problem with setting up a stack nginx proxy manager using portainer on my home server

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, portainer, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

I had this error while trying to setup a nginx proxy manager container using portainer,
portainer started without problems

error:

```
Recreating 3167b8f95097_nginxproxy_db_1 ... 
[1A[2K
Recreating 3167b8f95097_nginxproxy_db_1 ... [31merror[0m
[1B
ERROR: for 3167b8f95097_nginxproxy_db_1  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/data/compose/11/data/mysql': mkdir /data: read-only file system

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while creating mount source path '/data/compose/11/data/mysql': mkdir /data: read-only file system
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
: exit status 1
```

docker-compose.yml that i use in the create a stack option in portainer pasted in web editor

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose
      # - '21:21' # FTP
    environment:
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "npm"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "npm"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"
      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'npm'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'npm'
      MYSQL_USER: 'npm'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'npm'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Don't edit with "solved" or solution inside the question. Accepting the answer is enough. If you want to provide your own solution, you can do so in a self answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by creating the listed directories in a home folder and changing the file paths from relative to absolute.